Mi objeto auth()->user() no se autentica de manera correcta en las demás "rutas o vistas" en Laravel 9
Estoy tratando de autenticar a mi usuario de la base de datos, y al parecer cuando hago el login lo hace bien, pero cuando lo redirijo a la vista de perfil (profile.blade.php) y trato de mostrar la información de tal usuario me lo muestra como null:
Usuarios:

Controlador del login LoginController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    //Método para mostrar el login
    public function index()
    {
        return view('login');
    }

    //Método para hacer la validación
    public function validacion(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('correo', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            //regenerar el toke csrf
            request()->session()->regenerate();

            //dd(auth()->user()->nombre); //En este punto me muestra el usuario que se ha autenticado!

            //Reedirige a la vista del perfil ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
            return redirect()->route('profile')->with('success', 'Inicio de sesión exitoso');
        }
        return redirect()->route('inicio')->with('error', '¡Ocurrió un error, intenta de nuevo!');
    }
}



Mi archivo de rutas web.php
//Ruta para mostrar el perfil
Route::get('/profile', function () {
    return view('profile');
})->name('profile')->middleware('auth');


//Ruta para mostrar el login y hacer la autenticación
Route::controller(LoginController::class)->group(
    function () {
        Route::get('/', 'index')->name('inicio');
        Route::post('/login/auth', 'validacion')->name('loginAuth');
    }
);

Vista del perfil del usuario profile.blade.php

{{-- - Perfil de usuario  --}}
<div class="col-12 bg-white rounded-lg my-10">
 <div class="flex flex-col items-center pb-10 mb-10">
  <img class="w-28 h-28 mb-3 rounded-full shadow-lg" src="{{ asset('img/cat-masc.png') }}" />  
    <h5 class="mb-1 text-xl font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
        Nombre del usuario
    </h5>
    <span class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">TI</span>
 </div>
 <div>
  <p>Datos del usuario: </p>
  {{--- Aquí estoy tratando de mostrar el nombre del usuario logueado  --}}
  <h2>{{ dd(auth()->user()->nombre) }}</h2>
 </div>
</div>


Aquí muestro la imagen de mi error:

y también adjunto mi modelo:
User.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'usuarios';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre',
        'usuario',
        'password',
        'tipo_usuario',
        'status',
        'correo',
        'sexo',
        'id_rol',
        'id_area'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}

y el archivo config/auth.php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'table' => 'usuarios',
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];


Tienes que añadir el middleware 'auth' a las rutas donde quieras que se cargue la sesión en el request.

Primero que nada, hay que dejar en claro que la autenticación y mostrar los datos, son dos cosas diferentes. Creo que tu no tienes problemas con la autenticación, sino con las rutas.
Veo que estás retornando la vista, sin pasar el usuario como tal. Asi que vamos a probar con lo siguiente, que creo que es la solución. En el archivo de rutas vamos a cambiar esto:
Route::get('/profile', function () {
    return view('profile');
})->name('profile')->middleware('auth');

Por esto:
Route::get('/profile', function () {
    return view('profile', ['user' => auth()->user()]);
})->name('profile')->middleware('auth');

Esto, teniendo en cuenta que dices que te muestra el usuario autenticado anteriormente.
De todos modos, revisa en la vista profile que la sesión y autenticación permanecen activas, esto lo puedes hacer con:
auth()->check() //Tiene que devolver true, si retorna false, hay que enviar de vuelta al login

